# Intellij IDEA version info

Tags: editor, intellij-idea, versioning

I'm using IDEA 10.5 Community Edition.
I have several modules under different versioning systems (CVS or Mercurial).
I also have multiple tabs opened in editor. Is it possible to set IDEA so that in editor tabs I'd see the versioning info of the file? Is it also possible to se it so that I'd see versioning info of the file in Project window?

Answer (score 0):

IDEA doesn't have an option to display file revision. Why would you need it?

Note that you can configure tabs coloring for different modules/scopes so that file tabs for the files under CVS and Mercurial are in different color.

Comment: Hi. I don't want to disable it, I want to display it in an editor tab or beside the file in Project tab

Comment: OK, I need it so I can quickly see what branch a certain file is in, .... Or is there another way to see this

Comment: For CVS there is a feature request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-3638. For Git and Mercurial current branch is displayed in the status bar, for SVN you can see it in Changes | Subversion Working Copies.